# Out-of-order events caused by duplicates in Kafka partition

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

What could cause out-of-order events within a partition when the `ConsumerRecord` timestamp is identical in duplicates?

For example:

```
2021-03-28T10:05:06.435Z A
2021-03-28T10:05:10.939Z B
2021-03-28T10:05:06.435Z A
```

and no B event after it.

In kafka-streams config `processingGuarantee=at_least_once`, `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1` and `acks=all`

Topic config:
`ReplicationFactor: 3 Configs: message.downconversion.enable=false,cleanup.policy=compact,follower.replication.throttled.replicas=*,segment.bytes=1073741824,message.format.version=2.4-IV1,max.compaction.lag.ms=2592000000,max.message.bytes=1048576,min.compaction.lag.ms=259200000,min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.25,unclean.leader.election.enable=false,retention.bytes=-1,min.insync.replicas=1`